# Should I check user subscribe status via customerInfo in client or cloud funtion

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, revenuecat

I am new flutter developer and use firestore as my server, my question is for my flutter app I want to check user’s subscription status, so I can get it via

```
CustomerInfo customerInfo = await Purchases.getCustomerInfo();
```

Should I then pass this value

```
customerInfo.entitlements.all[entitlementID]?.isActive
```

directly to my cloud function to calculate different methods based on user’s subscription status, or I need to move revenuecat code part in cloud function, in case someone can hack my code and always pass TRUE value to my cloud function? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any part of your application code that runs on a user's hardware is possible to change, fake, or eliminate entirely.  The only secure way to run any code is on a backend you control, such as your Cloud Function.

Whether or not you should do this work on your frontend or backend is up to you - you decide if it's worth risking a problem with the code being run differently than you coded it. If it's a matter of user entitlements or billing, then consider if you want the user to bypass your controls (you probably don't).